# Mechanism of Octoxynol-10 as a preservative in vaccines

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

I noticed that the Fluarix Quad flu shot this season contains Octoxynol-10 rather than Thimerosal as a preservative. I am not expert in this area, so I did a Google search of "Octoxynol-10", and noticed that it has lysing properties and so speculated that this must be how it would kill any bacteria present and thus act as a preservative. Nonoxynol-9 is an active ingredient in anti-spermicides, I speculate for the same reason.

My question is: What does the Octoxynol-10 do when injected into my muscle tissue? I speculate that there may be some lysing of my cells. Perhaps only the cells with very thin membranes lyse? bacteria, sperm, nerve?